# How to insert html tag to selected text - summernote

Tags: jquery, summernote

I'm setting up textarea with summernote, and want to create custom button that can insert `code` html tag

I try create simple custom button from summernote documentation

this my code

```
var CodeButton = function (context) {
        var ui = $.summernote.ui;

        // create button
        var button = ui.button({
            contents: '<i class="fa fa-code"/> Code',
            tooltip: 'Code',
            click: function (value) {
                var range = $('#textarea').summernote('createRange')
                // invoke insertText method with 'hello' on editor module.
                context.invoke('editor.insertHtml', '<code>'+range.toString()+'</code>');
            }
        });

        return button.render(); // return button as jquery object
    }
```

let say I want to change `<p>test</p>` to be `<p><code>test</code></p>`, but code above doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

```
click: function (value) {
var text = context.invoke('editor.getSelectedText');
// You can initialize node with class instead of calling addClass.
var $node = $('<p><code">'+text+'</code></p>');

// http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#insertnode
context.invoke('editor.insertNode', $node[0]);
}
```